# How to handle when the x button is click on pop-up web page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp-classic, window

I have a “pop-up” web page inherits from System.Web.UI.Page in a plug-in which is a part of a large web framework.  The markup is inside `<asp:Content>` below.  I need to perform some actions (updating the page behind) when the user clicks on “Close” button (id = _close) and when the user clicks on the ‘x’ button on the right corner of the page.  My page is not displayed in the browser. I got the “onclick” (in the code behind) to work for “Close” button below, but I don’t know how to detect when the ‘x’ button is clicked.  I tried on `window.beforeunload` and `window.onclose`, it doesn’t work.  “Hello World” pops up when my web page opens and when I click “Close” (`_close`) button.
How do I handle for the click on the ‘x’ the same way when “_close” button is clicked?

```
 <script language="javascript">
      function doClose() {    alert('Hello World!'); }  window.onload = doClose();  // also tried with window.beforeunload </script>
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? If you have a pop-up, you can write your code to be executed in the window that opened the popup

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the code on the opener. Write a method in opener and execute it from the pop-up window.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Comment: Thank you for the post / example.  I'll use the example in the URL for my question, I need to update the "source" window when the 'x' button (close button) on the top right hand-side of the child window is clicked by the user.  I think I need to trap in the client script somehow.  Hope this makes my problem clear.